# How to combine proportional editing with vertex slide?

Tags: animation

So, I am trying to do some basic facial animations with shape keys, and I would like to do most of them with proportional, but also I need most of time to use vertex slide. When I try to do vertex slide + proportional it doesnt work.
Is there any practical way to do that?

Comment: I don't think there is, edge slide isn't really meant for operating on complex selections at once, let alone with proportional edit in the mix. But why edge slide specifically? Won't any of the editing operators work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Proportional editing will alter the connected edges which isn't really compatible with using it as a reference to limit the transformation.

If you change the [3D manipulator](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/orientations.html) to Normal you can restrict movement to an axis relative to the starting position of your geometry which might give the result you are looking for.

If the normal of the selected edges doesn't match what you are after you can make a [custom orientation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/orientations.html#custom-orientations) from the edge you want to follow before starting to move the vertices.